# UWP - Frame Navigate only crashes when passing a parameter

Tags: c#, uwp, navigation, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to pass the id of the clicked element as a string to a new page, however the app always crashes. I'm not entirely sure how to find out the cause of the problem as every example I've found uses the same method and it works just fine for them.

The sender event:

```
private void MovieBox_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var id = (sender as StackPanel).Tag as string;
    Debug.WriteLine(id); //the correct id in string
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(MovieDetailsPage),id);
}
```

The OnNavigatedTo event

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string text = e.Parameter as string;
    Debug.WriteLine(text);

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

The app crashes somewhere in between it seems like. Putting a breakpoint on the first event shows the correct id being sent, however it never reaches OnNavigatedTo.

I'm not sure what the problem is, as the second page loads just fine if I remove the parameter.

Edit:
I wrote the exception from the App.g.i.cs file:

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in MovieLibraryApp.exe
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in 
MovieLibraryApp.exe but was not handled in user code
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: m. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

And here is the xaml (it's kinda a mess atm): https://pastebin.com/GkXkxYDS

Also this:

```
Your parameter must be serializable. If it isn't, then use SessionState
```

The entire .cs page, though I haven't done any logic here yet as I never got the parameter to work.
MovieDetailsPage.xaml.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MovieDetailsPage
{
    public MovieDetailsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        if (e.Parameter != null)
        {
            string text = Convert.ToString(e.Parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue that you are facing. Also you are saying that the execution is never reaching OnNavigatedTo when a parameter is passed, can you check your page's constructor if the `InitializeComponent()` execution is completed? Also adding the exception that you are receiving would help us identify the issue..

Comment: Can you check whether debugger point hit the construcctor of MovieDetailsPage page or not.

Comment: @Pratyay I updated my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questioner was using Template10 (go to know about it during chat) so following is the final and updated answer for implementing Navigation.

**For Template10:**

way-1

```
using Template10.Services.SerializationService; 
... 
string id = (string)(sender as StackPanel).Tag; 
string str=SerializationService.Json.Serialize(id); 
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MovieDetailPage), str);
```

Way-2

```
var NavService = NavigationService.GetForFrame(this.Frame); 
NavService.Navigate(typeof(MovieDetailPage), id);
```

Comment: It seems I have exactly the same issue using this. :/

Comment: @JonasMohammed Please check update in my answer. Also share the exact exception you are getting.

Comment: @JonasMohammed I hope, there is no other issue on your MovieDetailsPage or current page.

Comment: @Guarang Dave sorry but it still crashes the same way. Also I'm not sure how to show the exception since it crashes between the navigation (and results in a UnhandledException). Surrounding it in a try/catch yields nothing. https://i.imgur.com/BlVOvCf.png

Comment: check you output window.. you will get the actual exception there.

Comment: @Pratyay Yeah I know I can check the output, but no exception is logged there, even if I try to catch the error when navigating. Is there another way I can find the exception?

Comment: Did you try setting a debug point in the constructor and check if the constructor execution is working correctly or not ? most probably you are getting the exception before OnNavigatedTo is called..

Comment: @Pratyay agree with you.

Comment: @JonasMohammed You can register UnhandleException handler in your app.xaml.cs file and check there for inner exception and also the image you shared, check into the details into argument e for the inner exception. As I mentioned in previous comments, there should be no error in other code. You can share constructor of navigating page to guide you for your issue.

Comment: Okay so it does reach InitializeComponent and immediately crashes after. @Pratyay However I'm not sure why as it works fine if I don't pass in a parameter?

Comment: @JonasMohammed Can you share code behind page (.cs) as well?

Comment: and also I hope that you are passing id only. no other complex type you are passing during navigation

Comment: @GaurangDave It's only a string, but a rather long one if that makes a difference: https://i.imgur.com/eBaBIpB.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169050/discussion-between-gaurang-dave-and-jonas-mohammed).

Comment: There's no reason to be calling this in a Dispatcher here, other than slowing down your code

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Earlier he did not mention that he was using Template10. That is why I suggested him to do Dispatcher.

Comment: Still no reason to use the Dispatcher at all if you're coming from a UI thread event (in this case OnTapped), you only need to do it if you're calling *not* from the UI thread