# UWP app, crash on this.Frame.Navigate

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP app, with two Pages: MainPage and EventPage. On both of these there is a splitView, and at the top of this a GridView with two buttons - one to navigate to MainPage, and one to navigate to EventPage. The XAML for the buttons looks like this:

```
<Button Content="Browse by system" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Margin="0,0,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="250"
        Click="SystemButtonClick"/>
```

However, when i press the "Browse by system" button, the app crashes. Here is the constructor for the page:

```
public EventPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var systemList = SystemClass.GetSystems();
        systemList.Sort();
        Systems = new ObservableCollection<string> (systemList);
    }
```

It passes the constructor fine, and instead crashes when exiting the eventhandler for the button click:

```
 private void SystemButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(EventPage));
    }
```

I've modeled this after the [Peer-to-peer navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages) tutorial from microsoft, and can't find any significant differences. The only similar issue I could find here was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848625/uwp-frame-navigate-only-crashes-when-passing-a-parameter), but that seemed to be due to the Template10 package which I'm not using.

When the crash does occur, it goes to the App.g.i.cs file and complains that the debugger isn't configured to debug this unhandled exception.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

EDIT: To add, if I click the button to move to the current page, it reloads fine. I also just tried starting the program to the EventPage, which also prompted a crash.

EDIT2: After some further testing, it seems I've located the source of the crash, though I don't understand it.

At the beginning of my EventPage class, I have a few variables:

```
public sealed partial class EventPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<EventBin> EventCollection;
    private ObservableCollection<String> Systems;
    public EventPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Systems = SystemClass.GetSystems();
    }
```

It seems that the crass occurs when I assign the Systems variable. This doesn't occur with my identical operation for the other page, with a different variable. The only difference being that in the MainPage, it's an ObservableCollection of a custom class rather than of strings.

If I re-initialize the System variable like this:

```
var Systems = SystemClass.GetSystems();
```

It runs, but doesn't connect to my bindings in the XAML.

Comment: Is it possible, that your systemList is null?

Comment: No, it's sitting at a healthy 40 elements.

Comment: Could you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to reproduce it?

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turned out that the issue was that I had bound a custom type to the list in my data template, and then tried feeding it plain strings.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="System_DefaultItemTemplate"
                  x:DataType="local:SystemClass">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Site}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Since the strings obviously didn't have any Name or Site properties, it crashed.

Comment: Just wanted to write that your binds will be te problems, because i wasnt able to reproduce your crash. Next time: To a minimal example your .xaml should be included